# Как использовать ant-построение jar в Maven'e?

Tags: maven, ant, java

Доброго времени суток.
Есть ant-скрипты, которые полностью собирают проект и генерируют war-файлы или jar-файлы. Необходимо перевести все скрипты в Maven. Но все это долго и тяжело. Нужен способ, при котором Maven использовал бы только этот ant-скрипт и делал на выходе именно ту jar или war, который делает ant. Есть некий [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/usage.html), который запускает ant-скрипт. Но что делать дальше после того как ant сгенерирует, к примеру, jar-файл? Мне бы хоть какой Hello World, который бы показал зацепку или какой совет.

Comment: Боюсь, вы намучаетесь с этим. Зная мавен и его воркфлоу, что-то впилить туда весьма проблематично

Comment: есть maven ant plugin - разберись с ним

Comment: удобство мавена в том что создать "dummy" проэкт очень просто, + не надо заботится об 3p dependencies. если у вас уже есть готовый ант скрипт для билда, то зачем тогда переходить на мейвен? погуглите ant ivy. если все же у вас веская причина для перехода на maven, то глупо было бы не воспользоватся его преимущствами